# if multiselect is.selected, find any select that hasClass of the selected.val() then enable that selected

Tags: select, find, multi-select, selectedvalue

How would I go about coding: if multiselect is.selected, find any select that hasClass of the selected.val() then enable that selected?

> var countryChange = $(this).val();
>
> if ($("#Countries option[value='"+countryChange+"']").is(":selected"))
>   {$(this).find($("#option").hasClass(countryChange)).prop("disabled",false);}

UPDATED:

> $("#Solutions option." + countryChange).prop("disabled",false);
>           $("#Solutions").selectmenu("refresh");

But the above only works if the country in question is selected, not if others are selected, as it's in an array.